# How to remove or change android EditText border bottom line color

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]

I want to change/ remove bottom line color. I traying many solution, I was change and remove background form EditText style but its nothing to work.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/TextInput">

    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
        android:id="@+id/etMobileNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:hint="@string/enter_receiver_phone_number"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLength="11"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="18sp"
        style="@style/EditText">

    </com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

```
<style name="TextInput">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/input_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hint_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/input_text_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/hint_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">20dp</item>
</style>

<style name="EditText">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_bottom_bar</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/input_text_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: In "EditText" style, add this line: background="null"

Comment: I wrote [a blog post](https://marconcini.dev/2017/04/19/styling-textinputlayout-and-textinputedittext.html) on how to style some of these things a couple of years ago. Most of it is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

it's very simple to change editText bottom line color programtically,
by adding this line in your activity class :

`editText.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(yourColor)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
android:background="@null"
```